# How do I prevent programs from restarting after forced reboot?

Tags: windows, windows-update, updates, reboot

I can live with the computer rebooting after windows updates are installed. But after it restarts, if I forgot to log out the night before, it *tries* to restart all of my programs. For one thing, few of them resume to a sensible state. And for another, there is contention of 10 or 20 programs all trying to compete for my attention at once.

How can I accept the reboot, but suppress the forced restart of the programs?

Comment: Which OS are you using? All my windows installs do not have anything running after a **reboot**.  Only when I suspend/resume it keeps programs running.

Comment: Only thing i've seen doing somewhat similar to what OP said is with Chrome & Firefox.

Comment: It shouldn't restart anything that is not included in the startup list, unless you have some provision to preserve and restore the previous session.

Comment: I'm using Windows 8.1, but I've had this behavior since 7 and also on Windows 10, so I figured it was a Windows thing, irrespective of version. I often have some combination of Chrome, FireFox, Visual Studio, SQL Management Studio, OneNote, Excel, Sublime, Slack, and maybe a few others running. Sublime is the only one that cleanly restores, but there is usually a few minutes of each program trying to jump to the front and steal focus to ask me something. If they all just stopped, and let me open them in my own order, it'd be great.

Answer (score 0):

You can turn off Automatic Updates in the Control Panel. When turned off you will be prompted every time with a message like "Windows Updates are installed, when would you like to restart?".

When you are running Windows 7 you can customize the update process, I dont know how well that works with Windows 8/10.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I'd rather not turn off updates. For one thing, our domain policy prefers to have them on and I'd rather not get into a debate over it. For another, it's a good thing and I'd rather have a reboot in the middle of the night than right when I get to work. I just don't like the behavior that after the reboot, my programs try (and fail) to recover their old state.

Comment: @ParchedSquid Try Windows Key + R > gpedit.msc > Computer Configuration > Admin. Templates > Windows Components > Windows Updates. Maybe you can find something there?

Comment: Thanks @mpboom! I think mentioning windows updates is a red herring. My problem has more to do with how windows tries to restore the session to its original state. It probably does that with an unexpected power outage or other unplanned, forced reboots.